# Docusign. Keep an envelope pending status

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm trying to create an envelope with 3 template roles. The problem is in a 3rd role. I don't know who is the 3rd guy at the moment and I need somehow to get envelope know that 3rd template role should be there, but I will update his name and email sometime in the future and for now I'm just passing his role and clientUserId(withouth name and email). Currently, after 1st and 2nd role complete their proccesses my envelope get status completed and it seems I can't update it anymore.

Here is my code. I'm creating envelope with all the roles and returning docusign url and envelopeId for the 1st role. Same would happen with the rest roles, knowing envelopeId:

```
const client = new docusign.ApiClient()
client.setBasePath('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi')
client.setOAuthBasePath('account-d.docusign.com')

const tokenResponse = await client.requestJWTUserToken(userId, integrationKey, ['impersonation', 'signature'], privateKey, 600)

client.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ` + tokenResponse.body.access_token)
const envelopesApi = await new docusign.EnvelopesApi(client)

const envelope = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, {
  envelopeDefinition: {
    templateId: templateId,
    status: 'sent',
    emailSubject: `Signing template ID: ${templateId}`,
    templateRoles: [
      { 
        roleName: args.firstRole, 
        name: args.firstSignerName, 
        email: args.firstSignerEmail, 
        clientUserId: firstRoleId 
      },
      { 
        roleName: args.secondRole, 
        name: args.secondSignerName, 
        email: args.secondSignerEmail, 
        clientUserId: secondRoleId 
      },
      { 
        roleName: args.thirdRole, 
        clientUserId: thirdRoleId 
      }
    ],
  }
})

const recipientView = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelope.envelopeId, {
  recipientViewRequest: {
    returnUrl: my local host,
    email: args.firstSignerEmail,
    userName: args.firstSignerName,
    authenticationMethod: 'none',
    clientUserId: firstRoleId
  },
})

return { url: recipientView.url, envelopeId: envelope.envelopeId }
```

Please, let me know If you know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is use a special type of [recipient](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/recipients/) that is called an [intermediary](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#intermediary-recipient).
An intermediary recipient can specify recipients of their own. This way the envelope doesn't have to have all the possible recipients when it's sent out initially.

Another way to do this is using the [Correct](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=oeq1643226594604&topicId=dxr1578456334187.html&_LANG=enus) option, which can be used to modify an envelope after it is sent. You can add the additional recipient at that point (via API call) and even add the tags for that new recipients even after the envelope is no longer in draft mode.

Comment: Hi @Inbar Gazit. Do I understand it right, the correct option is available if an envelope status is not completed.
In my case first two roles must sign it first and only after them the third role makes final signature. The problem here is that the third role comes sometime in the future and I can not predefine him, therefore when the first two roles sign the envelope it gets completed status. Do you know how to work around it?

Comment: You could use the "pause" option to stop the envelope after the second signer signs. See https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/pause-workflow/